# Why does stack not pass my ghc-options to the compiler?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

In the cabal file I specify the GHC options `-Wall` and `-O2`:

```
name:               Test
version:            0.1.0.0
build-type:         Simple
cabal-version:      >=1.8

executable Test
  hs-source-dirs:   src
  main-is:          Test.hs
  build-depends:    base >=4.8 && <4.10
  ghc-options:      -Wall -O2
```

When I compile the program Test.hs:

```
data Color = Red | Green | Blue

foo :: Color -> Int
foo Red = 0
foo Green = 1
-- foo Blue is intentionally missing!!
```

I get the error:

```
Preprocessing executable 'Test' for Test-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( src/Test.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/Test/Test-tmp/Main.o )

/home/user/Projekte/HaskellTutorials/Test/src/Test.hs:1:1: error:
    The IO action ‘main’ is not defined in module ‘Main’

--  While building package Test-0.1.0.0 using:
      /home/user/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-nopie/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --build
      dir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0 build exe:Test --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

The error about the missing main action is not the problem.
Look at the text at the end of the second last line:

> build exe:Test --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"

Why do I not see my GHC options *-Wall -O2*? (I fear, I did some stupid little mistake ...)

PS:
stack version is: Version 1.5.1, Git revision 600c1f01435a10d127938709556c1682ecfd694e (4861 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.17.1
LTS: 8.17

Comment: have you tried adding a dummy main (`main = putStrLn "It works!"`)to your `Test.hs`-file, each executable **must** include such a function. - I don't think ghc is interested in issuing warnings when there are more critical mistakes at hand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options `-ddump-hi -ddump-to-file` are being passed **by Stack to Cabal**.  Cabal then adds them to the options specified in the `.cabal` file before passing them along to GHC.

If you run Stack with:

```sh
stack -v --cabal-verbose
```

and search through the output, you'll see that your options *are* in fact being passed to GHC.

As @epsilonhalbe noted, GHC isn't complaining about the more minor issues when it discovers that `main` is missing, so if you add:

```hs
main = undefined
```

to the bottom of your program, you'll get the warnings you're expecting.